Как сделать автоматическую генерацию строк и колонок, чтобы получилась таблица
Подскажите пожалуйста.
С помощью каких сигнатур классов и xaml контрола можно реализовать такую таблицу, чтобы:

Кол-во строк генерировалось автоматически в зависимости от кол-ва  значений из источника, например коллекция студентов.
и автоматически генерировались колонки с названием предметов в зависимости от значений из источника, например коллекция предметов.
каждая пустая ячейка может принимать данные, чтобы можно было сохранить и показать снова.
Какие правильные сигнатуры классов использовать, (Класс студент - ФИО, Класс предмет - название предмета, как-то переделать их??).

Как миниатюра.


Количество строк и так будет равно количеству в источнике. В остальном же DataGrid.AutoGenerateColumns, который сгенерит колонки и позволит повлиять на процесс генерации.

Авто генерация вроде происходит по свойствам класса, а по значению и кол-ву элементов как сгенерировать колонки

Так по свойствам класса происходит автогенерация колонок, что вам и надо. А по количеству элементов генерируются строки как пункты списка же.

Делается это так
<DataGrid
        ItemsSource="{Binding Students, Mode=OneWay}"
        AutoGenerateColumns="True"
        AutoGeneratingColumn="OnAutoGeneratingColumn"


Количество строк и так будет равно количеству элементов в списке Students

AutoGenerateColumns="True" обеспечит автогенерацию колонок. Имена настраиваются так
private void OnAutoGeneratingColumn(object? sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
    string headername = e.Column.Header.ToString();

    //update column details when generating
    if (headername == "Name")
    {
        e.Column.Header = "First Name";
    }


В ячейке будет то что есть в источнике. Будет в источнике пусто - значит в ячейке пусто. По умолчанию колонка будет редактируемой (ну текстовая точно). Можно подправить колонку. Она доступна как e.Column (пример выше и есть пример правки) или создать полностью свою. Это сложнее, но вот пример.
private void OnAutoGeneratingColumn(object? sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
  string headername = e.Column.Header.ToString();


  if (headername == "Age")
  {
      var templateColumn = new DataGridTemplateColumn()
      {
          Header = "Student Age"
      };

      DataTemplate cardLayout = new DataTemplate();
      cardLayout.DataType = typeof(Student);

      FrameworkElementFactory spFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(StackPanel));
      spFactory.Name = "factory";
      spFactory.SetValue(StackPanel.OrientationProperty, Orientation.Horizontal);

      FrameworkElementFactory cardHolder = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBlock));
      cardHolder.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, new Binding("Age"));
      cardHolder.SetValue(TextBlock.ToolTipProperty, "Student Age");
      spFactory.AppendChild(cardHolder);

      cardLayout.VisualTree = spFactory;
      templateColumn.CellTemplate = cardLayout;        
      e.Column = templateColumn;
  }


Для простоты классы должны быть плоскими вида.
public class Student
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Math { get; set; }
    public int Biology { get; set; }
}



Если они таковыми не являются, то можно создать вьюмодель с плоским представлением.. Иначе придется переписывать биндинги в обработчике OnAutoGeneratingColumn. Ну тут кому что проще.
В общем, в OnAutoGeneratingColumn настраиваются и имена, и типы и вообще все. Также там можно отменить генерацию какой то колонки (документация)
upd: С порядком несколько сложнее. У колонки есть свойство DisplayIndex на эту тему, но я с ним дел не имел.

Плохое решение. Мешать все в одну кучу не лучшая идея, а вы сейчас именно это и делаете. С таким успехом проще сделать .Columns.Add(...); с нужными данными. Ну а если мы всеж хотим правильно и иметь весь контроль, то данные (да, название колонки - это данные) стоит выносить в отдельную коллекцию, реализовывать новое поведение контролу и через него привязывать уже данную коллекцию "данных колонок" (реализация всего этого). А вообще, дни недели - это коллекция, а не свойства по типу "имя", "возраст" и т.д., а в этом случае автоген. вряд-ли сгодиться.

Если так хочется UI патчить, то тогда уже юзерконтрол оформить бы следовало. С другой стороны, а зачем это всё, если есть DataTable?

@EvgeniyZ Плохое, не плохое - оно стандартное от майков. Я просто притащил сюда примеры из документации показав их как ответы на вопросы тс. Вот все вопросы к майкам почему не .Columns.Add(...); Что вы там про новичков говорили?! Хотите показать человеку альтернативные варианты - дерзайте.

Я уже показал альтернативный вариант с подробным описанием почему и как. Касательно документации - там описывается возможный функционал WPF да и C# в целом, это не значит, что так принято делать и так стоит делать. WPF это в первую очередь про привязки, а механизм привязок позволяет отделить данные от UI, ну а вы взяли и банально в UI оперируете данными, да еще и так топорно...

@EvgeniyZ Еще раз - это стандартный путь майков. Описан в документации. Я просто быстро ткнул носом в документацию. Потом нашлось чуток времени и быстро раскрыл суть написанного в документации. Можете ставить минус ответу и писать свой ответ. Что вы мне пытаетесь доказать? Что так нельзя? Так можно же - это рабочий вариант. Не самый лучший - пишите свой, тут можно давать несколько ответов. И автор выберет лучший. (По вопросу что должно быть в vm, а что в виде я могу с вами поспорить, но негде...да и зачем)

Не учите меня пользоваться ресурсом пожалуйста. Я дал комментарий под ответом, который считаю плохим. Написал его с целью предупредить других людей (включая автора вопроса) в том, что не стоит так делать, объяснил почему так не стоит делать и дал альтернативное решение (яб сказал дубликат, но да ладно...). Дальше уже, кому надо, кто захочет, тот поймет. Переубеждать кого либо я не собираюсь. Вы сделали банальный и бездумный копипаст с документации, ну чтож, радуйтесь, получайте теперь критику.
